# Stored procedure with 2 parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes 3 parameters: let's call them `@a,@b,@c` and all are optional.

In the stored procedure they are defined with this order : `@a,@b,@c`

Based on my research so far, from .NET code I should be able to call these in any order:

For example:

```
.Add(New OleDbParameter("@c", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "c", DataRowVersion.Current, c))

.Add(New OleDbParameter("@a", OleDbType.Integer, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, False, 0, 0, "a", DataRowVersion.Current, a))
```

But when I do this, stored procedure still thinks the 1st value passed is a and second value is c.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or some other RDBMS? The question is tagged as `sql-server`, but I am confused because I see you are using the `OleDbParameter` object. If you are using SQL Server, then you should use the optimized `SqlParameter` object instead.

Comment: Yes thisi s legacy code which is using older technology OLe DB

Comment: So if you want to use the parameters in any order, then you need to switch to a newer data access technology than `OleDb`, but if you are stuck with `OleDb`, then you need to make the order be correct.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, I wonder why you didn't put this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

OleDB does not support named parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: Use the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace objects (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameter`) instead.

Comment: Ahhhh. OleDB is junk.

Comment: `OleDb` is mid 1990's, while `ADO.NET` is 2002 to current.

Comment: Yes my current company is still sticking hard to outdated junk code.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to use the parameters in any order, then you need to switch to a newer data access technology than OleDb, but if you are stuck with OleDb, then you need to make the order be correct.

I thought Preston's answer sufficed, but I have posted this answer. If you feel it helps more, then accept it.